# I have a feed in xml format with some atom elemets , how to convert them in to java objects

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

I need to convert this xml to java objects please suggest me how to do that or give me an example

is converting atom feed into java objects is same as xml to java pojos ??

```
  <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <link href="https://exampleatomfeed.com"
     rel="current"/>
   <link href="https://exampleatomfeed.com"/?limit=25&amp;search=&   amp;direction=backward"
     rel="self"/>
   <id>urn:uuid:6e392ca6-3f9e-4e70-a2ed-81306e216ee7</id>
    <title type="text">/events</title>
   <link href="https://exampleatomfeed.com"?marker=urn:uuid:35639090-   c125-4349-bc9f-73c5f28ae98a&amp;limit=25&amp;search=&amp;direction=forward"
     rel="previous"/>
   <link href="https://exampleatomfeed.com"marker=urn:uuid:d7c91521-59c7-47de-8ebc-dcc3f1cbd621&amp;limit=25&amp;search=&amp;direction=backward"
     rel="next"/>
   <link href="https://exampleatomfeed.com"?marker=last&amp;limit=25&amp;search=&amp;direction=backward"
     rel="last"/>
   <updated>2015-10-08T09:14:28.043Z</updated>
   <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <atom:id>urn:uuid:35639090-c125-4349-bc9f-73c5f28ae98a</atom:id>
  <atom:category term="tid:965965"/>
  <atom:category term="rgn:ind"/>
  <atom:category term="dc:Ind"/>
  <atom:category term="iid:a0cb9f59-39f9-4dbc-b318-1d2121f8be8e"/>
  <atom:category term="example"/>
  <atom:category term="type:example"/>
  <atom:category term="example"/>
  <atom:category term="original_message_id:eda6dc40-f035-4ae5-931c-d214c184fa51"/>
  <atom:title type="text">Server</atom:title>
  <atom:content type="application/xml">
     <event xmlns="http://example.com"
            xmlns:gova="http://example.com"
            dataCenter="SYD2"
            endTime="2015-10-08T00:00:00Z"
            environment="PROD"
            id="35639090-c125-4349-bc9f-73c5f28ae98a"
            region="IND"
            resourceId="a0cb9f59-39f9-4dbc-b318-1d2121f8be8e"
            resourceName="RS-6"
            startTime="2015-10-07T00:00:00Z"
            tenantId="965965"
            type="USAGE"
            version="1">
        <nova:product bandwidthIn="127886662"
                      bandwidthOut="4236174"
                      flavorId="3"
                      flavorName="1GB Standard Instance"
                      isManaged="false"
                      osLicenseType="WINDOWS"
                      resourceType="SERVER"
                      serviceCode="ddfdffdf"
                      status="ACTIVE"
                      version="1"/>
     </event>
  </atom:content>
  <atom:link href="https://example.com/entries/urn:uuid:35639090-c125-4349-bc9f-73c5f28ae98a"
             rel="self"/>
  <atom:updated>2015-10-08T02:13:26.523Z</atom:updated>
  <atom:published>2015-10-08T02:13:26.523Z</atom:published>
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: i tried to un Marshalling but confused with atom tag and feed

Comment: For JAXB you need some Java classes for holding this data, or an XML schema describing its format. Otherwise, read into a DOM tree etc.

Comment: removed double question, took out question from quote block

Answer (score 0):

That's possible using XML adapter when unmarshal. Look in this link:

http://aquiseprograma.co/2015/10/como-agregar-la-etiqueta-cdata-a-etiquetas-de-un-xml-generado-por-jaxb/

It's in spanish but is to easy understand. There is applying CDATA when marshal.